# LOAD DATA INFILE should fill up empty values with specific content

Tags: mysql, concatenation, file-io, ifnull

LOAD DATA INFILE should fill up only empty values with a specific content.

CSV:

```
Value1, Value2
-------------- 
1       123345 
2        
3       678901
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
Value1, Value2
--------------
1       123345
2       k0000123345
3       678901
```

`LOAD DATA INFILE .... SET .... ean = IFNULL(@d3, CONCAT('k0000',an))`

...will result in still empty database values.

Comment: Please - post some sample data and illustrate what is failing here. Almost anything might be wrong, or right, with this.

Comment: The mysql statement works but ean is empty when doing this instead of containing "k00001234" if csv has empty value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using LOAD DATA INFILE an empty field in the input file is treated as an empty string (for string types) An empty string is not the same as `null`.

So for your input, your empty fields will fail the `IFNULL()` test. Check the length of the incoming data in your field and concatenate if it's zero:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE .... SET .... ean = IF(CHAR_LENGTH(@d3)>0,@d3,  CONCAT('k0000',an))
```